# unused arguments lib epitools name expected in Rstudio

Tags: r, spatial

when I do analysis

```
newdata$E<-expected(newdata$population, newdata$DBD, 4)
```

I get

```
Error in expected
(dbd_temporary$population, dbd_temporary$DBD, 4) :
  unused arguments (dbd_temporary$DBD, 4)
```

notes: newdata$E is a new column to combine newdata$population and newdata$DBD. in newdata has no variable/column named E

How do I stop getting the error message again?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.